# Advanced custom fields in Wordpress issue

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I combined a jQuery slider with the repeater fields.
under the repeater, I have 2 subfields. one called “image_carousel1” and the other “image_carousel_discription”

This slider has a class called “sc-selected” that dynamically appear when an image is selected. (when this class is on an image the image changes it’s size).

```
  <?php

 // check if the repeater field has rows of data
  $i = 1;
  if( have_rows(‘carousel_images’) ):
 // loop through the rows use_cases_fields data
 while ( have_rows(‘carousel_images’) ) : the_row();
   $title=get_sub_field(‘image_carousel_discription’);
   $image = get_sub_field(‘image_carousel1’);

     if( !empty($image) ):
 // thumbnail
$thumb = $image;
  ?>

  <li id=”image11″ data-row=”<?php echo $i; ?>” > <a
   href=”#home”>“/>
<h2 id=”change_h2″ data-row=”<?php echo $i; ?>”><?php
    echo $title ?></h2>

   <?php $i++; ?>

  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php
  endwhile;
 endif;
 ?>
```

JS- the “carousel on” adding the class “sc-selected” to image.

```
   carousel.on(‘itemSelected.sc’, function (evt) {

$(“#change_h2”).each(function(index, elem){

 $(“#image11”).each(function(index2, elem2){
  var itemH3 = $(elem).attr(‘data-row’);
    var itemImg = $(elem2).attr(‘data-row’);

   if (itemH3==itemImg){
  var div1 = document.getElementById(“change_h2”);
var align = div1.getAttribute(“data-row”);

  console.log(align);

}
 });
 });

});
```

I’m trying to define that when the class “sc-selected” is on some image and the “data-row” is equal in “image11” and “change_h2″ the “image_carousel_discription” form the same row of the “image_carousel1” will appear,(I defined that in JS func)

This is the code that displays the images and the titles.

My problem is with the JavaScript function, the data row always stays on the first row and in every image that is selected it keeps showing in console log “1” (the first data-row)

Comment: In the HTML, is there really an `i` in `image_carousel_discription` (i.e. it should probably be `description`)?

Comment: Side note: if you want people to read your code, make sure it's properly indented.

Comment: Ye that was a spelling mistake, so? this is not the reason that it's not working..

Comment: If it's just a spelling mistake here, I suggest you edit your post and put an 'e' as one would expect. And as you're at it, make sure to fix the indentation (remove tabs if you have some that way it's easier to see that the indentation is correct.)